# How can I custom-make big Facebook and Twitter share button like this?

Tags: php, html, css, facebook, wordpress

First of all, I’m aware that the FB “share” button has been deprecated but the thing is that I happened to find this site 22words.com and really like the big FB and Twitter share buttons appearing at the end of all posts.

Does anyone know how to do it exactly like that?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use:

```
<a href='https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=THELINKTOSHARE'>Share on Facebook</a>
```

and add your own styles to make it look however you want.

For Twitter use:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/home?status=THELINKTOSHARE">Share on Twitter</a>
```

Comment: Thanks I could see that when my mouse hovers over the two big buttons. Possible to go a little deeper on this? I mean, if I want to have these two big buttons at the end of each and every of my posts, how can I do it? use shortcode? Your further help would be much appreciated...

Comment: You need to style the link with css. I made a VERY quick and simple [JSfiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/6SeTX/) to give you an idea of what I'm saying.

Comment: That certainly helped, thanks a lot Mark! The reason I mentioned shortcode was that I've installed a premium framework(in this case, Genesis and Dynamik) on my site and don't know what would be the most efficient way to insert these two big buttons to the end of each and every of my posts...possible to give a hand here? Much appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with those frameworks, so I'm not sure what kind of setup you have. To insert the buttons, my first choice would be to find the code that wraps each of your posts and integrate the new share buttons directly, then add style in your CSS. However, you might not have this kind of access/flexibility with your template, in which case shortcodes sound like a good option. If you need help with that check out [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress-shortcodes-the-right-way--wp-17165)

Answer (score 1):

Using Your Facebook user name and password log in [FacebookDeveloper](https://developers.facebook.com) Site

Then click DOC Menu --> Sharing --> Social Plugins

In that page you can see 11 Facebook plugin(Like,Share,etc) codes for JS,JQ,HTMl,etc are available..

Just copy the code and past in into your source code... Simple  :)

Answer (score 0):

for facebook

`<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fparse.com" target="_blank">
 <img src="YOURIMAGEURL" />
</a>`

for more brief details [Click here](http://www.joshuawinn.com/facebooks-sharer-php-longer-deprecated-2014/)

Answer (score 0):

To actually insert this into WP paste this in your functions.php file: 
See the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content)

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_the_content_filter', 20 );

function my_the_content_filter( $content ) {
        $content .= '<div class="social"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='.get_permalink().'">Share on Facebook</a>';
        $content .= '<a href="https://twitter.com/home?status='.get_permalink().'">Share on Twitter</a>
        </div>';   
    return $content;    // Returns the content.
}
```

Add your images and CSS.